# Prove that ratio is $k=2/5$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

Let $E , G , F , H$ be the midpoints of sides $AB , BC , CD , DA ,$ respectively of quadrilateral $ABCD.$ The common points of segments $AF , BH,CE,DG $ divide
each of into three parts, as shown in the figure.
Given that $$\frac{LK}{GD}=\frac{LI}{AF}=\frac{IJ}{BH}=\frac{JK}{CE}=k$$
Find $K.$ And also construct the $ABCD$ such that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and still satisfies the condition. Additionally, prove that $LIJK$ is a trapezoid.

[image]

The answer is $2/5.$ And I want an elementary proof. The question's subpart was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4385111/prove-that-abcd-is-a-parallelogram) and We think a separate new question should be there to discuss about the elementary method.

Note that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram. And $Ar[ABCD]=2Ar[EFGH].$ And define $M=AC\cap BD.$ Note that $$2k^2\times Ar[MIJ]=2 Ar[MHB]=2Ar[MEB]=Ar[MAB].$$

Hence, we have $2k^2\times Ar[IJKL]=Ar[ABCD]\implies 2k^2\times Ar[IJKL]=Ar[EFGH].$

Comment: Which is exactly the statement of the problem? Do we know that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram or not? Do we have to find $k$ (or $K$?!) or not? Do we have to show that $LIJK$ is a trapezoid or not? The elementary proof should be given for which proposition explicitly? Please take time and separate in a clear manner what is given and what is wanted. The information on *the* subpart is also unclear, which subpart of the linked question is relevant here? And what should be constructed? The quadrilateral $ABCD$? (... which is in fact given in the problem - taking $ABCD$ a square for instance is ok?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to spend as few words as possible. The figure should be self-explanatory.
[image]

First of all notice as basic fact
$$
[ADE]+[CBG]=[BAF]+[DCH]=\frac12[ABCD],
$$
which implies
$$
[AFCH]=[BGDE]=\frac12[ABCD].
$$

Let $M$ be the intersection of the bimedians $FH$ and $EG$. As well known and can be trivially proven $M$ bisects both bimedians.

Consider the quadrilateral $BGDE$ (first figure). Since $M$ is the midpoint of $EG$ we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
[BMG]=[BME]\\
[DME]=[DMG]
\end{cases}\implies
[BMG]+[DME]=\frac12[BGDE]=\frac14[ABCD],
$$
which implies:
$$
[IMJ]+[LMK]=\frac k4[ABCD].
$$
Applying the same argument to the quadrilateral $AFCH$ and summing the results one obtains:
$$
[IJKL]=\frac k2[ABCD].\tag1
$$

The second figure tells us:
$$
[ALE]+[BIF]+[CJG]+[DKH]=[IJKL]\tag2
$$

From the third figure we have:
$$
[ABF]=2[ALE]+[BIF]+k[ABF]\implies (1-k)[ABF]=2[ALE]+[BIF]\tag3
$$

Summing the equation $(3)$ for all four triangles $ABF,BCG,CDH,DAE,$ one finally obtains:
$$
(1-k)[ABCD]=3[IJKL]=\frac{3k}2[ABCD]\implies k=\frac25.\tag4
$$

Comment: But how did you construct the quadrilateral?

Comment: I have assumed that the quadrilateral is convex. No other assumptions were made.

Comment: No, I meant you how can you assure it is true for some quadrilateral that is not parallelogram? You said for this ratio it can hold, but we need to verrify

Comment: In the other answer I have shown necessary and sufficient condition for ensuring all four ratios to be equal. In this answer I only demonstrated an elementary derivation of the value of the ratio ($k$) under **assumption** of equality of the four ratios. No other assumptions are required for this derivation.